# Update time to datetime in mysql

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have a table, with column `start_time`, which is of type time, and `start_date`, which is of type date.

I would like to have `start_time` be a datetime, and `start_date` to still exist as a date.

My first attempt of converting start_time to be a datetime was along the lines of

```
UPDATE TABLE `event` MODIFY `start_time` datetime;
```

But this doesn't work, since a time is not sufficient data. Is there a nice way of doing something like

```
UPDATE TABLE `event` MODIFY `start_time` datetime = `start_date` + `start_time`;
```

(obviously that syntax is totally wrong, I'm just trying to give a picture of what I want)

Thanks

Comment: First Change `filed type` to `datetime`. Then run your first query.

Answer (score 0):

Try `CAST(CAST(start_date AS datetime) + start_time AS datetime)`.